# React Router or Semantic UI React causing issue with rendering components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

This is my code in  App.js:

```
import { useRecoilValue } from 'recoil';
import { authState } from './atoms/authAtom';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import { ProtectedRoute } from './layout/ProtectedRoute';
import CourseDashboard from './features/course/CourseDashboard';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from './features/nav/Navbar';
import { LoginPage } from './features/auth/LoginPage';

export const App = () => {
  const authentication = useRecoilValue(authState)

  return (
    <>
      <ToastContainer position='bottom-right' hideProgressBar />
      <NavBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/courses' element={
          <ProtectedRoute user={authentication?.user} isAuthenticated={authentication?.isAuthenticated} redirectPath={'/login'}>
            <CourseDashboard />
          </ProtectedRoute>
        } />

        <Route path='/' element={
          <ProtectedRoute user={authentication?.user} isAuthenticated={authentication?.isAuthenticated} redirectPath={'/login'}>
            <CourseDashboard />
          </ProtectedRoute>
        } />

        <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
```

This is in index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { App } from './App';
import { RecoilRoot } from 'recoil';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import './styles.css'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RecoilRoot>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </RecoilRoot>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I am using Recoil for state management, Semantic UI React for styling and React Router DOM v6 for routing.

For some reason, the NavBar element renders at the top of the page but the components below the NavBar like the CourseDashboard or LoginPage never render.

[image]

This is my login page:

```
import { Container, Form, Input, Text } from "semantic-ui-react";

export const LoginPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Form>
        <Input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" />
        <Input name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" type="password" />
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};
```

If i comment out the semantic UI part and just use html elements like this:

```
import { Container, Form, Input, Text } from "semantic-ui-react";

export const LoginPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {/* <Form>
        <Input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" />
        <Input name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" type="password" />
      </Form> */}

      <h1>login</h1>
    </>
  );
};
```

it renders:

[image]

I have been banging my head for hours and couldnt find the reason. Can someone figure out whats going on? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Taking a comment into consideration, check the DOM and looks like the LoginPage component renders, but for some reason its behind the NavBar component although they are separate components. Any idea how to separate them and render the LoginPage component below the NavBar?

[image]

This is the NavBar Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Menu, Container } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { authState } from "../../atoms/authAtom";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { SignedInMenu } from "./SignedInMenu";

export default function NavBar() {
  const authentication = useRecoilValue(authState);
  console.log(authentication);

  return (
    <Menu inverted fixed="top">
      <Container>
        <Menu.Item as={NavLink} exact to="/" header>
          <img
            src="/assets/logo.jpg"
            alt="logo"
            style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}
          />
          Bhaktivedanta Vedic Academy
        </Menu.Item>

        <Menu.Item name="Courses" as={NavLink} to="/courses" />

        {authentication?.isAuthenticated && <SignedInMenu />}
      </Container>
    </Menu>
  );
}
```

Comment: Seems like a semantic-ui issue then if the routing and regular JSX content is rendering as expected. Can you inspect the DOM to see what is actually rendered there? If the elements are there then check the CSS that is being applied.

Comment: You were right. the components are rendering, but for some reason, they are rendering on the same spot.

Comment: How is the `NavBar` rendering to the screen? What is the CSS it is using? (*See [mcve]*) It either needs to be part of the inline UI layout, or the "page content" needs some top margin/padding to "push" it down below the space the navbar occupies visually.

Comment: its all Semantic-UI-React. i am not sure how to add direct css to Semantic Components

Comment: I don't see any specific "navbar" component in that [library](https://react.semantic-ui.com/), so what *specific* components are composed to make your `NavBar` component?

Comment: added code for the NavBar component

Comment: My guess here is that the `fixed="top"` prop is absolutely positioning the elements, so the rest of the content renders underneath (*"stacked" under the element, not below it visually, if that makes sense*), so adding the top margin/padding to the content "area" could resolve this layout issue. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that reproduces this issue we could inspect live?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253635/discussion-between-sriram-arunachalam-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NavBar` component uses fixed positioning which takes it out of the DOM layout flow and the other elements render underneath it starting from the top of the view. You could solve this by adding `padding-top` to each routed component you are rendering, or as a more trivial solution, via a layout route component that renders `NavBar` and an `Outlet` into a `div` element that applies the `padding-top` CSS rule. The `NavBar` is *about* 44px tall, so anything around this value will be enough.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./features/nav/NavBar";

const AppLayout = () => (
  <div className="app-layout">
    <NavBar />
    <Outlet />
  </div>
);
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<AppLayout />}> // <-- Layout wraps all routes
    <Route
      element={
        <ProtectedRoute
          user={authentication?.user}
          isAuthenticated={authentication?.isAuthenticated}
          redirectPath={"/login"}
        />
      }
    >
      <Route path="/courses" element={<CourseDashboard />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<CourseDashboard />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

```css
.app-layout {
  padding-top: 3.25rem; /* 45px from base 14px font size */
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image: Edit react-router-or-semantic-ui-react-causing-issue-with-rendering-components]